# System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform for Class Library

Tags: c#

I want to create one library. I use .net Core 3.1 and here I have code below

```
public static IDbConnection CreateConnection()
{
    try
    {
        var conn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString);
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed) { conn.Open(); }
        return conn;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw new Exception(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

in debug when it comes to new SqlConnection line it throws error below

> ```
> System.Exception : System.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.
> ```

I don't know why this error occurs.
My architecture is below image
[image]

How can I solve this error ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Its successor: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Data.SqlClient

Comment: yes I uploaded it from nuget. @madreflection

Comment: I think you missed the point.  The difference is "System" vs. "Microsoft". You're not using the one with "Microsoft" in the name. That's the one that's supported on .NET Core and will get future updates.

Comment: Why the try/catch, if all you're gonna do is rethrow with the same message? Just let the exception happen normally. It's also safe to always call `conn.Open();` in this situation, without the `if()` conditional first. In other words, the size of the method can reduce by more than half.

Answer (score 0):

Remove System.Data.SQLClient amd install:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Data.SqlClient -Version 3.0.1
```